# MP3 stream returning WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, filter, urlstream

Currently streaming an mp3 with the following code:

```
NSString *stream = @"http://k003.kiwi6.com/hotlink/o4ywrn3ejt/Exodus.mp3";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stream];
    NSURLRequest *urlrequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webview loadRequest:urlrequest];
```

This works fine within the simulator however when run on a device returns with

```
Starting WebFilter logging for process BVC
2017-05-24 22:41:00.596535 BVC[9762:4179522] WF:_userSettingsForUsermobile: {
    filterBlacklist =     (
    );
    filterWhitelist =     (
    );
    restrictWeb = 1;
    useContentFilter = 0;
    useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
    whitelistEnabled = 0;
}
2017-05-24 22:41:00.599518 BVC[9762:4179522] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
```

Allow Arbitrary loads is set to Yes

Any ideas and or thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

open: Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme

Click on the run  Then ARGUMENTS

inside Arguments click Environment Variables

paste this inside

[image]

Comment: using OS_ACTIVITY_MODE flag may hide other important system information. 
this hides the issue from the log without addressing it at all.